# Running Unix Commands sequentially using a file

Tags: perl, unix, command

I intend to run unix commands sequentially using a file.
The commands include running perl scripts.

Comment: Isn't shell script work?

Comment: If you have to ask this question then I think you're out of your depth...

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is a bash script.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "my bash script"
mkdir "tmp"
perl my_perl_script.pl
```

Save this to file `script.sh`

You can now run it with

```
bash script.sh
```

or you can run it like a normal executable:

```
chmod a+x script.sh # set script as executable
./script.sh
```